# spark RDD union action very slow

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 spark RDDs, dataRDD and newPairDataRDD which are used for spark SQL query.
when my application init, the dataRDD will be initialized. All data in one specified hbase entity will be stored to dataRDD.

When client's sql query comes, my APP will get all the new updates and inserts to newPairDataRDD.
the dataRDD union the newPairDataRDD and register as table in spark SQL context.

I found even 0 record in dataRDD and 1 new inserted record in newPairDataRDD. It will takes 4 seconds for union. That's too slow

I think it is not reasonable. Anyone knows how to make it quicker? Thanks
simple code as below

```
    // Step1: load all data from hbase to dataRDD when initial, this only run once. 
    JavaPairRDD<String, Row>  dataRDD= getAllBaseDataToJavaRDD();
    dataRDD.cache();
    dataRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
    logger.info(dataRDD.count());

    // Step2: when spark sql query coming, load latest updated and inserted data from db to newPairDataRDD

    JavaPairRDD<String, Row> newPairDataRDD = getUpdateOrInstertBaseDataToJavaRDD();
    // Step3: if count>0 do union and reduce

       if(newPairDataRDD.count() > 0) {

        JavaPairRDD<String, Row> unionedRDD =dataRDD.union(newPairDataRDD);

    // if data was updated in DB, need to delete the old version from the dataRDD.

        dataRDD = unionedRDD.reduceByKey(
            new Function2<Row, Row, Row>() {
            // @Override
            public Row call(Row r1, Row r2) {
             return r2;
             }
            });
    }
//step4: register the dataRDD
JavaSchemaRDD schemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(dataRDD..values(), schema);

//step5: execute sql query
retRDD = sqlContext.sql(sql);
List<org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.Row> rows = retRDD.collect();
```

From the spark web ui, I can see below. Apparently it needs 4s for union

Completed Stages (8)

StageId Description Submitted   Duration Tasks: Succeeded/Total Input Shuffle Read Shuffle Write

6 collect at SparkPlan.scala:85+details 1/4/2015 8:17   2 s 8-Aug       156.0 B

7 union at SparkSqlQueryForMarsNew.java:389+details 1/4/2015 8:17   4 s 8-Aug   64.0 B      156.0 B

Comment: Are you sure it's union? The operation just concatenates partitions so doesn't really take time.

Comment: Please post your code. Perhaps there is an important detail that explains the time. As Sean said, this shouldn't take that much time.

Comment: there is cache operation which should be time-demanding

Comment: I know the cache need time, but in my post the time just for union. I have updated my post and added the spark web ui running result. even the ＲＤＤ１ has no data. when the ＲＤＤ２has 1 data. From the spark web ui running result. you can see it takes 4s just for union and 2s for collect().

Answer (score 0):

What you're monitoring is the time for the two .count() calls, not for .union(), which is grouped in the same stage by the scheduler and is, indeed, a very long call in Spark.